# How to set Asciidoc toc.section.depth value from simple 'asciidoctor file.txt -o file.html' command?

Tags: docbook, tableofcontents, asciidoc, asciidoctor, docbook-xsl

[This FAQ section](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/faq.html#_the_asciidoc_toclevels_attribute_does_not_work_with_docbook_outputs_why) describes how to set the "section depth"/"TOC level"/toclevel shown in the table of contents. However, I've no idea how to implement this in my simple:

```
$ asciidoctor my.txt -o my.html
```

command. Does anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `toclevels` attribute controls this.

From https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-toc-levels:

> By default, the TOC will display level 1 and level 2 section titles.
>   You can set a different depth with the `toclevels` attribute.
>
> ```
> :toc:
> :toclevels: 4
> ```
>
> 1. The `toc` attribute must be set in order to use toclevels.
> 2. `toclevels` is set and assigned the value 4 in the document’s header. The TOC will list the titles of the section 1, 2, 3, and 4
>      levels when the document is rendered.

Comment: See related [discussion/issue at asciidoctor's github area](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1398).